# Apache mod_rewrite urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a url like the following:

```
http://www.domain.com/us/en/
```

that I would like to redirect to:

```
http://www.domain.com/en_US/
```

what is the simplest way to achieve this?

Thank you.

**Edit:** This would be dynamic for many language location combos.

**More info**: a more simplistic question would be is there a way to get all of the variables from the first URL and use them in the second url for a proper redirect.

```
http://www.domain.com/a/b/c/d
```

To:

```
http://www.domain.com/d/c/b/a
```

Comment: Do you want to uppercase first URI segment like `us=>US, uk=>UK` etc

Comment: yeah, that would be ideal

Comment: Well that requires changes in Apache server config? Do you have control over that?

Comment: yes, I do have control over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in Apache config:

```
RewriteMap uppercase int:toupper
```

and restart the server.

Then add this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ /$2_%{uppercase:$1}/ [L,R]
```

> For `http://www.domain.com/a/b/c/d` To: `http://www.domain.com/d/c/b/a`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$4/$3/$3/$1/ [L,R]
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that I can use $1 $2 $3 for the /a/b/c/ in the original url and use them in the second url to reorder them how I wish?

Comment: what is the [L,R] used for?

Comment: yes exactly that it is what it does. Each `([^/]+)` captures segment from original URI in `$1, $2, $3` etc.

Comment: `R` is for Redirect (change URL in browser) and `L` is for marking rule as `Last` which injects this rule for further processing by mod_rewrite loop.

Comment: Since I have your attention and you have been very helpful thus far. is there a conditional I can use for say. if $1 == "foo" then rewrite it as "bar"?

Comment: yes definitely that rule will be like this: `RewriteRule ^foo/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /bar/$3/$2/$1/ [L,R]`

Comment: wow, ok thank you for all your help. This will save me hours of data entry work. I have been charged with a task that needs almost 3000 urls redirected to their new urls to preserve SEO.